# Erro ao fazer ligacao entre tabelas BD

Tags: sql-server

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: Esquema]

Estou a tentar ligar a tabela lição as faltas. Estou a usar a tabela "Licao_Faltas" para fazer a ligação, mas não me  esta a deixar ligar a "faltas_Id" da "licao" a da "licao_faltas"

Help Please.

Comment: ADicione o schema das tabelas. Sem saber como elas são, fica complicado ajudar.

Comment: Adicionado :)..

Comment: Não entendi bem o seu modelo, mas tem um jeito que você conseguir ligar com esta modelagem. Altera esse seu modelo alterando a chave primária de Licao_Faltas só para Faltas_id. Depois você liga Faltas em Licao_Faltas pelo Falta_Exp e depois o Licao_Faltas com Licao. Deve funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples, você está tentando fazer a associação de uma chave simples com uma chave composta.

E ambos os lados do relacionamento devem conter os mesmos campos, remova a chave composta da tabela(Licao_Faltas) faça o relacionamento e aplique a chave novamente, isso deve funcionar.

Comment: Pois da. Mas Eu na tabela -Licao_Faltas- se só puser a chave primaria Faltas_Id não consigo ter um registo único. E se puser a "Falta_esp" para primaria, depois nao consigo fazer a ligação entre -licao- e -licao_faltas-.

Comment: Deixe a tabela sem nenhuma chave depois aplique a chave composta

Comment: Consegue scriptar sua base em um.sql e me enviar?

Comment: Alias já consegui. Mando por onde?

Comment: Coloca em um http://pastebin.com/ e manda o link

Comment: Ja resolvi. Afinal não era preciso a tabela intermédia de "Lição_Faltas". 

Obrigado de qualquer maneira.